# How to query logcli in python and store it in a python variable (preferably in json format)

Tags: python

I want to query a logcli query in python and store the output of the logcli query in a python variable. The logcli query is

```
logcli query '{app="events-collector"}'
```

How can I do this? Moreover, can I preferably store it in some kind of array or json file?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Loki's HTTP API](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/api/), or you could treat *logcli* just as any other system command and use one of python's utilities to execute commands.
[subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) worked for me. Here is a script that works on my Mac:

```
import subprocess
import json
import pprint

logcli_command = "logcli --addr=https://your-loki-url.com --org-id=undefined -o raw query {app=\"events-collector\"} --limit=10"
logcli_command_as_list_of_args = logcli_command.split()

process = subprocess.Popen(logcli_command_as_list_of_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

list_of_json_records = [json.loads(line) for line in process.stdout.readlines()]

print(f"{len(list_of_json_records)} records returned.")
pprint.pprint(list_of_json_records[0])
```